# LINQ not working in Views. Any ideas how to fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, view

System.Linq doesn't seem to be referenced in any of my views, even though *it is*. Any LINQ code in any of my views appears as it does in this image, and Intellisense doesn't work

[image]

However, the LINQ code *does* work in all of my .cs files, and the code in the views still *works* when I run the solution.

when I hit Alt+Enter I get a little message "Failed to import method".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Linq referenced in Pages section of web.config

```
 <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        ........... 
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        ................
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Comment: web.config inside Views folder, not the main one!

Answer (score 0):

I would check these in the following order -

1. System.Linq reference in the project references.
2. Target Framework should be .NET 3.5 or Above
3. Is the file ReadOnly ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the DLL does not have "copy local" set to False - worked for me.